# Javascript - Facebook Message in Cordova Application with facebook plugin - method: "send"

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, message, send

I'm not able to send a message with facebook using the Cordova Plugin.

```
function fbMessage(description){
    var options  = {
        method: "send",
        caption: '',
        link: '',
        description: description,
        to: '100003725222912'
    };
    facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog(options,
        function(dialogSuccess) {
        },
        function(dialogFaliure) {
        }) 
}
```

the message doesn't compare in the page.
I'm sure I connect to facebook with my application.

The Error is:

> Error Domain = com.facebook.sdk.share Code = 202 "The operation couldn't be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.share error 202.)" UserInfo=0x7967aa0{com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Message dialog is not available.}

Comment: Pretty sure the Send dialog is not available on mobile devices, but for desktop web only.

Comment: @CBroe no, I have tryed who weeks ago and it was working. But now is not working and I didn't understand why.. The last time the only things not working was specify the person to send a message.

Comment: Facebook interaction with your app might be disabled, chk that in iPhone settings...

Comment: @SappyGoofy Thank you, now it's working! I logged in facebook from the iPhone settings. I don't understand why the connection to facebook from my app is not enough to send the message. Another problem is: now I can open the window's message and write it inside and send it but the recipient of the message is not compiled automatically, the var 'to' of the object option is not read correctly, maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install Facebook Messenger App, the error message doesn't appear anymore and the send dialog shows up. It works on smartphones. For android tablets, you need to fill the name, caption and description as well, only the link and method won't work. In iPad, however, it seems to not work yet.